# Retrieve Facebook id from username

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I would like to retrieve a Facebook user's id given their username.

Example: Given `helloworld` return `100003263065603`.

I understand that the Graph API does not allow this anymore, but several sites, such as [lookup-id](https://lookup-id.com/) and [findmyfbid](http://findmyfbid.com/) are able to do this.

I am guessing they are doing some sort of scraping? If so, how would I implement this in Node.js

Answer (score 1):

Those sites most likely scrape the profile page, which is not allowed. Don´t do that, should not need to anyway. Just let the user authorize your App and you will get his (App Scoped) ID. There´s no serious application for using the username or his global ID anymore.